# Fastapi error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for long requests. What is the mistake?

Tags: python, cors, fastapi

To access the API from the front, I use ngrok.exe http 80. When making requests from the fronted API, data filtering is performed that lasts 10min+, but the problem is that I get an error on the front after 5 minutes...

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://0c79-37-112-0-90.eu.ngrok.io/integration/start_filter 'from origin ' Here was the url of the front' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The backend seems to have the corses set up the way they should.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from .routers.router import router

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
CORSMiddleware,
allow_origins=["*"],
allow_credentials=True,
allow_methods=["*"],
allow_headers=["*"],
)



app.include_router(router)
```

The question is, is the error due to the backend or ngrok and can it be fixed? I executed requests from the front, requests and postman are the same everywhere, only errors were treated differently

Comment: can you add the response headers when you call your route ? maybe you have something filtering some headers like a nginx config

Comment: Check the response headers in Postman. Are you able to see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` there?

Comment: I have also the same problem and I could not find a solution. CORS issue only happens in the added router. Any one found a solution for this?

Comment: I see a wildcard for origins and allow credentials true, check FastAPI CORS middleware subsection for allow_credentials.